# How to implement Magnetic Scrolling in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to provide smooth scrolling through sections on my web page **Though anchor tag is a solution but I do not want to use the anchor tag to go to that section** .Instead I want the user to scroll just a bit so that it smoothly slides to the next immediate section of the page.

> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap

I tried using scroll-snap but in that case also when we scroll to section 2 a small part of section 3 is visible.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to listen to mouse scroll elements and move to the anchor tags accordingly with a little bit of animation to make it look smooth. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No haven't tried that, can this be achieved without anchor tags, just with the scroll events and css?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap